# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'lawyer_id' cannot be null

Tags: database, laravel-5.7

Error While storing the data in the database ..

I'm storing the data in the database but it gives as error,that Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'lawyer_id' cannot be null "

```
public function lawyersDiplomaInfo(Request $request){
            $dipInstitution = $request->get('diploma_name');
            $dipYear =  $request->get('diploma_year');
            $all_params = $request->keys();
            $total_dipFile = preg_grep("/^dip_file_.*/", $all_params);
            if($dipInstitution != null && $dipYear != null){
                $lawyer = new Lawyer();
                $data = new LawyerDiploma();
                $data->lawyer_id = $lawyer->id;
                $data->diploma_institution = $dipInstitution;
                $data->year = $dipYear;
                $data->created_at = Carbon::now();
                $data->updated_at = Carbon::now();
                $data->save();
            }

            for($i = 0; $i < count($total_dipFile); $i++){
                if($request->file('dip_file_'.$i) != null){
                    $filename = $request->file('dip_file_'.$i)->store('diplomafile');
                    $files = new DiplomaFile();
                    $files->diploma_id = $data->id;
                    $files->file = $filename;
                    $files->save();
                }
            }
        return ['message' => 'Data Added'];
    }
```

in the line  **$data->lawyer_id = $lawyer->id;** it is giving an error.

Comment: try changing it from `$lawyer->id` to `$lawyer['id']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo create $lawyer two lines up ($lawyer = new Lawyer()) of $data->lawyer_id = $lawyer->id so you need to set $lawyer params before asign it to $data.